# How to make good editText for entering addresses?

Tags: java, android

I want ONLY the `editText` can be scroll-able. How to do it? As shown in the image below, when user enter the address, the `editText` becomes like that. Can someone help me, which part do I miss?

Java coding:-

```
        final EditText yourMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contactMsg);
```

XML Coding:-

```
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/contactMsg"
        android:layout_width="288dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="390dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_clipboards"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Message"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
```

[image]

Comment: use `android:singleLine=true` inside your xml file in EditText.

Comment: add your full layout code.

Comment: Cannot paste all the coding, too long hmm :'(

Comment: add more snippet of code to check your layout is `Linearlayout` or `Relative layout`

Comment: @RatilalChopda I'm using DrawerLayout...

Comment: @Radhey I still cannot make the editText scrollable. Its to enter the address data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

You must enable scrolling inside the EditText programmatically:

```
contactMsg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.inputFormComments) {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Try it if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure what you mean by making the `editText` look better, but for the Toast:

```
Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And you can place this code after the email has been sent.

Comment: As you can see based on the photo above, the editText clash with the Send Button when I try to input long messages....

Comment: Try removing `textMultiLine`

Comment: Now, I'm using textLongMessage instead of textMultiLine. But how I want to enter without moving the boxes?